# retrieve multiple substrings from a string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe contains strings of email addresses with the format:

```
d = {'Country':'A', 'Email':'123@abc.com,456@def.com,789@ghi.com'}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and I want the username of emails only. So the new dataframe should look like this:

```
d = {'Country':'A', 'Email':'123,456,789'}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The best way I could think of is to split the original string by comma, delete the domain part of emails and join the list back again. Are there better ways to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string as output, you can remove the part starting on `@`. Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with the `@[^,]+` regex:

```
df['Email'] = df['Email'].str.replace(r'@[^,]+', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
  Country        Email
0       A  123,456,789
```

For a list you could use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Email'] = df['Email'].str.findall(r'[^,]+(?=@)')
```

Output:

```
  Country            Email
0       A  [123, 456, 789]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex question, not really a Pandas question but here's a solution that'll return a list (which you can join together as a string)

```py
import re

df['Email'].apply(lambda s: re.findall('\w+(?=@)', s))
```

Output:

```
0    [123, 456, 789]
Name: Email, dtype: object
```

Comment: Version which would also join using a comma is: `df['Email'].apply(lambda s: ','.join(re.findall('\w+(?=@)', s)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Country':['A', 'B'], 'Email':['123@abc.com,456@def.com,789@ghi.com', '134@abc.com,436@def.com,229@ghi.com']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['Email'] = df['Email'].str.findall('@\w+.com').apply(', '.join).str.replace('@','')
df
```

Output

```
Country Email
    A   abc.com, def.com, ghi.com
    B   abc.com, def.com, ghi.com
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# iterate through the dictionary values are replace anything after @ and , or '
d={k:   re.sub(r"@[^,\']+",'' , v)   for k, v in d.items()}
d
```

```
{'Country': 'A', 'Email': '123,456, 789'}
```